# Getting hartid in non-M mode

Tags: riscv

I am continuing my development of RISC-V RTOS/Hypervisor. To obtain hartid, checking the mhartid CSR is necessary, but mhartid can only be accessed in M mode. Therefore, RTOS operating in S mode or Hypervisors in HS mode do not have a direct way to determine their hartid.

Upon inspecting OpenSBI, I noticed that OpenSBI sets hartid in the a0 register during BOOTLOADER initialization and passes it to BOOTLOADER as a startup argument. I am considering adopting a similar approach for RTOS and Hypervisors to receive hartid as a startup argument. However, I have some concerns.

Is this method of receiving hartid as a startup argument part of the official RISC-V International specifications? What if another RTOS does not adopt this method for receiving startup arguments? What if a Hypervisor does not implement passing hartid as a startup argument? In such cases, the likelihood of proper functionality seems significantly compromised.

I did not come across such wording in "The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume II: Privileged Architecture Document Version 20211203." Do you have any insights on this matter? I apologize if I overlooked any relevant information.

Comment: I doubt that you will find this in RISC-V specs as this is not part of the architecture but a software issue. Most of the bootloaders or kernels I have seen use a0 to pass the hartid. Linux also does that. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/riscv/boot.rst One may think that why we don't have this as part of SBI, for this I would refer this thread. https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/riscv-sbi-doc/issues/25

Comment: The term "specification" that is not within this specification feels very distorted. Despite being a substantial "specification" in the current situation, not officially specifying it could become a problem in the future. However, considering the current circumstances, there is no other choice, so I will adhere to this "specification." Thank you.